# Can I create a DbSet in a context class in Entity Framework Core to fetch the data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am getting back to Entity Framework after long delay. Now working in Entity Framework Core on .NET 6.

I have a need to create a stored procedure which join to multiple tables and return data. No tables exist in the SQL Server database for this data which is being returned based on joins over multiple existing tables.

See this example: I have table for `Bus` and `Route` and defined the same in the Entity Framework in the context class.

```
public class Buss
{
    [Key]
    public int RouteId { get; set; }
    public string Route { get; set; }
}

public class Route
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RouteId { get; set; }
    public DateTime  Started { get; set; }
    public DateTime Ended { get; set; }
}
```

And defined them in context class as well as:

```
public virtual DbSet<Bus> Busses { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Route> Routes { get; set; }
```

Then I have a stored procedure that and want to get the data based on inner join on them. See the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetRoutes
AS
    SELECT
        b.Route, r.Started, r.Ended, ref.Id 
    FROM
        Route r
    INNER JOIN 
        Bus b ON b.RouteId = r.RouteId
```

Note that the data it returns has no `DbSet` class defined in the Entity Framework. So should I create another `DbSet` class in the `DbContext`?

My confusion is that I think `DbSet` classes only created for the tables that exists in the database where as the data returned from the stored procedure could be anything so what should I do to handle the situation when a stored procedure returns data for which a class does not exist?

Please help me to understand and get the data successfully without an error.

Comment: I use EF for queries and projections based on tables (and some views) accessible through DbSets, and Dapper for any other queries based on stored procedures or views. But that's just one way to do it. EF offers several ways to return SQL query data. Look for Entity Framework + raw SQL queries and you'll find them. It's largely opinion-based which option suits you best.